# PL SQL - statistics query

Tags: plsql

I need help with the following query: For a HR oracle schema (table EMPLOYEES), make a statistics. First column is a year from HIRE_DATE. It should be distinct with ascending order. Second column should be months from HIRE_DATE. They should appear in natural order (January, February,...) and they should be distinct. Third column should be the number of hired people for each year and a month.

I have tried the following:

```
select distinct TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(HIRE_DATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY'),'Month') AS Month_, ltrim(TO_CHAR(HIRE_DATE,'yyyy'),'0') AS Year_
--count(ltrim(TO_CHAR(HIRE_DATE,'yyyy'),'0')) AS Num_of_employees
from employees
group by HIRE_DATE;
```

Could someone help?

Comment: I  couldn't understand your question.

Comment: please edit your question to make it clearer and attach the correct tags (this is not plsql). ideally show example input and output records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're quite close with your current query, but you appear to have misunderstood how aggregated queries work. You have a group by (which is correct), and also a distinct - you don't need the distinct, as aggregate queries output a single row per group.

From your question, it looks like you want to find the count of employees hired each month, so month and year are your group. Then you simply need a count to find the number of employees per month.

That means your basic query would look something like:

```
select trunc(hire_date, 'mm') mon_yr, -- truncates the date to the start of the date's current month (e.g. 25th Jan 2019 would get truncated to 1st Jan 2019)
       count(*) num_employees
from   employees
group by trunc(hire_date, 'mm');
```

Once you have that, it's easy to to split the date into it's constituent parts whilst retaining the ordering, e.g.:

```
select to_char(mon_yr, 'yyyy') yr,
       to_char(mon_yr, 'fmMonth') mon, -- used fm in the format model to avoid the extra spaces that would be returned without it
       num_employees
from   (select trunc(hire_date, 'mm') mon_yr,
               count(*) num_employees
        from   employees
        group by trunc(hire_date, 'mm'))
order by mon_yr;
```

N.B. In your original query, you were using `TO_DATE()` on something that is already in DATE datatype. Please do not **ever** do this, because if you do, Oracle has to do some implicit conversion, meaning `to_date(<date>, '<some format mask>')` becomes:

```
to_date(to_char(<date>, '<nls_date_format>'), '<some format mask>')
```

and if your the format of your nls_date_format parameter doesn't match the format mask you've asked for, an error will most likely occur.

You can use to_date on something that is a string, and to_char on something that is a date, but please never use to_date on a date or to_char on a string.

Comment: Years and months should be distinct. Also, months should be sorted from January to December.

Comment: Years and months **are** distinct and ordered correctly; did you not try the final query? If you don't understand how aggregate queries return one row per group (i.e. the columns in your group by) then you need to research them more, and also play around with them to understand them better.

Comment: See this: https://imgur.com/a/MYyc5YP This is the output of your query. It is not right.

Comment: How is it not correct? The years are in ascending order, the months are in "natural" month order, and each year-month combination is unique. That's what your question asked for, isn't it?

Comment: There should be only one 2002 year for example, but you have more. Month are not in natural order: January, February, March, ... December.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could edit your question to include some sample data in your table and the expected output. Are you saying that you want 2002 to appear only for the first row in that year, and blank to be displayed for the remaining months? Are you expecting month-years with no employees to be displayed?

Answer (score -1):

Think the below is what you are after?

```
SELECT to_char(hire_date, 'YYYY') year, to_char(hire_date, 'Month') month, count(*) 
FROM employees 
GROUP BY to_char(hire_date, 'YYYY'), to_char(hire_date, 'Month') 
ORDER BY to_char(hire_date, 'YYYY'), to_date(to_char(hire_date, 'Month'), 'MM');
```

Comment: Your order won't be right; it'll order the month column alphabetically and not in month order.

Comment: Years and months should be distinct.

Comment: @Boneist - true - code amended to order by year/month num instead of alphabetical.

Comment: @user10966491 no need for distincts when there is a group by, look through results of SQL and you will see there is only one row for each year/month combination.

Comment: @JordenAllcock that order by won’t work; you’re trying to convert a string such as “July     “ into a date using “mm” as the format mask. That’ll error.